# Hello I want to insert zero before the decimal value but its getting skipped and getting into the loop following procedure was created find the error

Tags: vba, ms-word, decimal

```
Public Sub addzerobfrdecimal()
```

cleanfnd
Selection.find.Execute findtext:="([.][0-9]{1,}[\ ])", MatchWildcards:=True, Forward:=True
St = Selection.RANGE.Start
ed = Selection.RANGE.End
ActiveDocument.RANGE(St, ed).Select
If Selection.find.found Then
Selection.find.Execute findtext:="([.][0-9]{1,}[\ ])", ReplaceWith:="0\1", replace:=wdReplaceOne
Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter, 1
Selection.find.Execute findtext:="([.][0-9]{1,}[\ ])", MatchWildcards:=True, Forward:=True
Else
MsgBox "Unable to find the occurance", vbCritical
End If
End Sub

Comment: Is the number part of a larger text or is it a pure number? If it is a number, your attempt cannot work: The content of the cell (=value of the number) doesn't change. Set the number format for such cells

Comment: @FunThomas - it's a Word question, not Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me all you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace where:

```
Find = ([!0-9])(.[0-9])
Replace = \10\2
```

You don't even need a macro...